# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRow' to type 'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store <System.Data.DataRow> in regid Column

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am stuck in adding dataset values into datatable with for loop. Please see the code and help me. It throws error like expected int32.

```
string allCtries = string.Empty;
allCtries = com.COUNTRY_ID;
string[] splitctrs = new string[] { };
splitctrs = allCtries.Split(',');
string m_Query = string.Empty;
DataSet dsPck = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("regid", typeof(int)),
                                                    new DataColumn("cid", typeof(int)),
                                                    new DataColumn("pid", typeof(int)) });
foreach (string val in splitctrs)
{
    dsPck = con.GetDataSet("select  registrationid, country_id, product_id from registration where product_id = " + com.PRODUCT_ID + " and country_id = " + val + "", CommandType.Text, ConnectionState.Open);
    DataRowCollection drr = dsPck.Tables[0].Rows;
    foreach (var row in drr)
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    //if (dsPck.Tables[0].Rows.Count> 0)
    //{
    //    dt.Rows.Add(dsPck);
    //}
}
```

Comment: Have you already tryed use Int32 instead int?

Comment: Yes .i tried int32 , int64 also  but throws error.

Comment: throws error in this place  dt.Rows.Add(row);

Comment: Check if all fields in database table "Registration" are int and NOT NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dsPck.Tables[0].Rows) 
{
    dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
}
```

instead

```
DataRowCollection drr = dsPck.Tables[0].Rows;
                foreach (var row in drr)
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
```